# grails .removeFrom when object exists elsewhere in class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, has-many, removechild

So essentially I have two classes:

```
Class User {
  String Name
}
Class Project {
  User requestedBy
    static hasMany =
    [
      assignedTo: User  
    ]
}
```

Now, I can set the requestedBy to say, User 1.
I can also do Project.addToAssignedTo(User 1).

The problem comes when I want to remove the user from assigned to when they already exist as the requestedBy. I can remove other users without problem:

Project.removeFromAssignedTo(User 1).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

I get no errors of any kind, the data just simply does not get removed. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When defining multiple relationships to the same class, you should define the bidirectional relationship, and [use the `mappedBy` property](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html) to define both sides of that relationship:

```
class User {
  String Name

  hasMany = [requestedProjects: Project, assignedProjects: Project]

}
class Project {
  User requestedBy
    static hasMany =
    [
      assignedTo: User  
    ]

    static mappedBy = [requestedBy: 'requestedProjects', assignedTo: 'assignedProjects']

}
```

Hopefully that solves your problem.

Comment: It complained about an owner not begin defined. I defined the owner and it still gave the same error. Really though there shouldn't be an owner. A project isnt owned by a single person, and certainly a user is not owned by a project. Any ideas?

Comment: `belongsTo` doesn't imply one-to-many or one-to-one.  It has more to do with defining the "responsible" domain class.  The `belongsTo` class is the one that is responsible for saving relationships in a many-to-many.  See [the docs for more](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html).  Try adding `belongsTo` to the `Project` class, and see if that helps. `static belongsTo = [requestedBy: User, assignedTo: User]`